# Explanation of Metadata API process

Tags: apex, soap-api, integration, metadata-api

Let me start by saying I have never worked with any of the Salesforce API's and I'm trying to understand just how they work.

I am attempting to make Metadata API calls from one salesforce org to another salesforce org to retrieve metadata. My app will most likely be a java app on heroku (it doesn't seem to me like I can make the calls directly from one saleforce org to another)

Here's the scenario, org1 makes a call to heroku and heroku calls org2 to get metadata to pass back to org1.

What I don't understand is,

1. which org should i generate the WSDL from?
2. Assuming I wanted to make the same call to another org, org3, do I need to generate WSDL for that org as well?

any explanantion will be greatly appreciated. Also if it's possible to make the call directly using APEX, please point me in the right direction

Answer (score 4):

You only need one copy of the Metadata WSDL. The API is the same for all orgs. It doesn't matter how many orgs you are connecting to, so long as the version of the API is supported in that org. In other words, you couldn't use the Winter '17 API in a Summer '16 org, but you can use the Spring '16 API in a Summer '16 org (the current release).